# swift 3 - HTTPCookieStorage cookies for url cannot call

Tags: swift3, httpcookie

I'm trying to fetch an array of the cookies for a specified url and get the following error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type '[HTTPCookie]?'
```

This is the syntax:

```
        if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: baseUrl) {

            for cookie in cookies {

            }

        }
```

What's the problem?

Comment: How your `baseUrl` is declared?

Comment: @OOPer Wow. It was a string and not a URL. Thanks